# ORACLE SQL Group By STILL giving Duplicates

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, duplicates

Have been working on this the whole day.

Following query returns around 162,000 records. Handful of them are duplicates.

Really, I'm not sure how else to troubleshoot.

This database pulls from external database for which I only have READ Access.

For example, if I have two rows

`20684 2/26/2019 11:13:04 AM abra 123 abc 6 abra`

`20690 2/26/2019 11:13:04 AM abra 123 abc 6 abra`

I would like to keep `20684 abra 123 abc 6 abra`

`20684 is the unique`I.INCIDENTID`that is not included in`GROUP BY`

Please assist.

```
   SELECT TO_CHAR(MIN(I.INCIDENTID))      AS "Incident ID",
          I.CREATIONDATE                  AS "Creation Date",
          M.MESSAGESUBJECT                AS "Email Subject",
          MO.IPADDRESS                    AS "IP Address",
          MO.DOMAINUSERNAME               AS "Login ID",
          MO.ENDPOINTMACHINENAME          AS "Computer Name"
   FROM        MESSAGE M 
   LEFT JOIN   INCIDENT I 
   ON          M.MESSAGESOURCE = I.MESSAGESOURCE 
   AND         M.MESSAGEID = I.MESSAGEID
   AND         M.MESSAGEDATE    = I.MESSAGEDATE 
   LEFT JOIN   MESSAGEORIGINATOR MO
   ON          M.MESSAGEORIGINATORID = MO.MESSAGEORIGINATORID
   LEFT JOIN   MESSAGEEXT ME
   ON          ME.MESSAGEID = M.MESSAGEID
   LEFT JOIN   INCIDENTSTATUS S
   ON          S.INCIDENTSTATUSID = I.INCIDENTSTATUSID
   LEFT JOIN   CUSTOMATTRIBUTESRECORD C
   ON          C.CUSTOMATTRIBUTESRECORDID = I.CUSTOMATTRIBUTESRECORDID                    
   GROUP BY    I.CREATIONDATE,
               M.MESSAGESUBJECT,
               MO.IPADDRESS,
               MO.DOMAINUSERNAME,
               MO.ENDPOINTMACHINENAME
```

Comment: Well then you are most likely missing some join somewhere.  Nobody here can fix that for you. Using the antiquated join syntax does not help.  See here https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/joins.php

Comment: How do you define a "Duplicate"?

Comment: @JNevill Rows are duplicate, i.e. row one has `abra 123 abc 6 abra` and row two also has `abra 123 abc 6 abra`

Comment: @OldProgrammer Thank you for link

Comment: Since you are using a `group by`, then that suggests the two rows are not duplicates. One has at least on of those GROUP BY columns slightly different. Since they are slightly different, which one of the two would you want to keep and why?

Comment: @JNevill in my example, there is also unique ID. So in the query, I said keep the unique ID that is minimum. So these two columns are duplicate, `20684 abra 123 abc 6 abra` and `20690 abra 123 abc 6 abra` and I would like to keep  `20684 abra 123 abc 6 abra`

Comment: Again, among all of the columns in your group by which define a distinct record, there is a difference between these two records returned `20684` and `20690`. Which column, that is in your GROUP BY, is different between those two records? Determine which of the two values in that column you feel is the most accurate and then put in logic to choose that one using an aggregate function.

Comment: @JNevill Oh now I understand. Yes, in the code `I.INCIDENTID ` is the column that is different, but it is not in `GROUP BY`. And I even put `MIN` around it, i.e. `MIN(I.INCIDENTID)`

Comment: If even after putting `MIN()` around it and not including it in the group by, you are still getting duplicates, then there must be at least one other column in your group by that is different between the two records you've identified as a duplicate.

Comment: @OldProgrammer I updated the code with joins, still having same number of duplicates ....

Comment: @JNevill Will check other column again....

Comment: You've got a lot of string columns there which look like they may be entered as free text. Remember that different case or invisible characters such as trailing spaces, `bell`, etc will still generate difference in the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @APL will try to apply `LTRIM` AND `RTRIM`....

Comment: Simplify to find a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @jarlh I simplified the code

Comment: Great, now show us a sample of the current result, and also the corresponding wanted result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If CREATIONDATE is a date data type it contains the time element down to seconds.  It's highly unlikely that the Incident Id's you're looking for the lowest of will have the exact time.  Format the date to a ISO Date and the GROUP BY will ignore the time differences.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(MIN(I.INCIDENTID))      AS "Incident ID",
          to_char(I.CREATIONDATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd') AS "Creation Date",
          M.MESSAGESUBJECT                AS "Email Subject",
          MO.IPADDRESS                    AS "IP Address",
          MO.DOMAINUSERNAME               AS "Login ID",
          MO.ENDPOINTMACHINENAME          AS "Computer Name"
   FROM        MESSAGE M 
   LEFT JOIN   INCIDENT I 
   ON          M.MESSAGESOURCE = I.MESSAGESOURCE 
   AND         M.MESSAGEID = I.MESSAGEID
   AND         M.MESSAGEDATE    = I.MESSAGEDATE 
   LEFT JOIN   MESSAGEORIGINATOR MO
   ON          M.MESSAGEORIGINATORID = MO.MESSAGEORIGINATORID
   LEFT JOIN   MESSAGEEXT ME
   ON          ME.MESSAGEID = M.MESSAGEID
   LEFT JOIN   INCIDENTSTATUS S
   ON          S.INCIDENTSTATUSID = I.INCIDENTSTATUSID
   LEFT JOIN   CUSTOMATTRIBUTESRECORD C
   ON          C.CUSTOMATTRIBUTESRECORDID = I.CUSTOMATTRIBUTESRECORDID                    
   GROUP BY    to_char(I.CREATIONDATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd') 
               M.MESSAGESUBJECT,
               MO.IPADDRESS,
               MO.DOMAINUSERNAME,
               MO.ENDPOINTMACHINENAME
```

Comment: I tried it and got even more duplicates. I also tried `ltrim(rtrim(to_char(I.CREATIONDATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd')))`, but no effect :-(

Comment: I marked this as the answer, because it will help most people. However I am still struggling. I believe this has to do with `NULL` in many fields, which I am still troubleshooting.

Comment: `TRIM(I.CREATIONDATE)` seems to work (to give unique results)

Comment: @Marium Maybe the join between MESSAGE and INCIDENT should be inner and not left outer if you'e looking for a lowest value from the right table?