# ORACLE SQL Trim ineffective with Regular Expressions

Tags: sql, oracle, trim, regex-negation

#### CLARIFICATION

When I simplify the [query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56027804/oracle-sql-group-by-still-giving-duplicates?noredirect=1#comment98701230_56027804), i.e.

```
   SELECT TO_CHAR(MIN(I.INCIDENTID))               AS "Incident ID",
          TRIM(TO_CHAR(I.CREATIONDATE,'DD-MON-YYYY'))           AS "Creation Date"    
   FROM   INCIDENT I  
   GROUP BY TRIM(TO_CHAR(I.CREATIONDATE,'DD-MON-YYYY'))
```

I get

[image]

But if I incorporate into my actual query for 164,000+ distinct rows, I get

[image]

But I expect this (only difference is, Creation Date must have proper Date format, not this complex string)

[image]

#### ORIGINAL QUESTION

I am reading a date-time from an external Oracle Database, and have trimmed any extra spaces successfully with `TRIM(I.CREATIONDATE)`.

I have verified this because my SQL query only displays distinct date values

However, `TRIM(I.CREATIONDATE)` turns `2/26/2019 11:05:44 AM` into `26-FEB-19 11.05.43.925000 AM`, but I only want `26-FEB-19`

When I apply regular expression to only get date, i.e. `REGEXP_SUBSTR(TRIM(I.CREATIONDATE),'[^ ]+')`, it certainly outputs `26-FEB-19`, but somehow extra spaces are added because I get duplicate dates.

I have tried applying `TRIM` a second time, i.e. `TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(TRIM(I.CREATIONDATE),'[^ ]+'))`, but I still get duplicates

Then I tried running regular expression first, then trim, but this does not work, i.e. `TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(I.CREATIONDATE,'[^ ]+'))` still gives duplicates.

Please assist

Comment: `GROUP BY TRIM(TO_CHAR(I.CREATIONDATE,'DD-MON-YYYY'))` cannot produce multiple rows for the same date.

Comment: I am still confused. You said 'I only want 26-FEB-19' in your original post but you expect '31-JAN-19 12.22.34.78300 PM' in your update.

Comment: @GenWan No, No, I expect `31-JAN-19`. However the query only works if I do only `TRIM`, which produces the long, complex date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `trunc()`, not `trim()` to remove the time component.

So try:

```
trunc(i.creationdate)
```

Or if you want the days in a particular string representation:

```
to_char(i.creationdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Comment: Hello, `TRUNC` gives `2/26/2019 12:00:00 AM`, and it doesn't remove whitespaces. Tried `TRIM(TRUNC)`, and somehow the whitespaces remain......

Comment: Also tried `TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(TRUNC(I.CREATIONDATE),'[^ ]+'))`, but no luck :-(

Comment: @Marium . . . The time component is all set to the same time component, so you get the date values only.

Comment: I clarified my question

Comment: For all intents and purposes this works ... but I believe I am having different issue for which I opened new post ....

Answer (score 1):

Try to_char:

```
trim(to_char(column_name,'dd-mon-yy'))
```